# htc android.credentials.INSTALL

Tags: android, certificate, htc-android

I am trying to add a CA certificate programatically in a HTC Desire S device Android version 2.3.5 and HTC Sense version 3.0.

I am using the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.credentials.INSTALL");
    intent.putExtra("name","testCA");
    intent.putExtra("CERT", bytes);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CA_CERT_ADDED);
```

I am populating the variable "bytes" correctly with the certificate bytes. When I run the code the dialog appears stating that I am installing a CA certificate, however the dialog is not populated by the certificate name that I pass in.

On other types of devices (non htc) I do not have this problem. It is only HTC devices.

Has anyone else ever come across this before and is there a solution to it.

Thank you in advance